# How to hide rows on the basis of dropdown menu?

Tags: excel, vba

i am new to VBA and i can´t really understand, how to solve the following problem:

I have an excel spreadsheet, representing balance sheet of the company:

```
A. Assets
1. Intangible assets   YES 
1.1. AB         12
1.2. ABC        0
1.3. ABCD       3
2. Tangible assets      NO
2.1. B         0
2.2. BC        0
2.3. BCD       0
```

I have a dropdown menu (YES/NO). YES, if there are number in a subgroup and No if sugroup is empty. So that Intangible assets would be YES and Tangible assets would be NO.

I need a macro, which will hide rows, if there is No in dropdown menu. In our case rows 2.1. - 2.3. must be hidden. Is there a possible solution to this problem?

As far as I understood, one can use this code:

Option Explicit

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$C$1" Then
    If Range("C1").Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows("2:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Range("C1").Value = "No" Then
        Rows("2:4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

This code is only for rows 2-4, how can I extend it?

EDIT:

Is it possible to extend the last piece of code, so that it will hide rows then NO, and bring them back if YES. Something like:

```
If Not RowsToHide Then
    RowsToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = False
If RowsToHide Then
    RowsToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End If
```

End Sub

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same data in your screenshot:

1. Add a header line (we need one line above the data for the formula to work)
2. Add a helper column in column D and insert the following formula into D2 (and copy it down)

   ```
   =IF(C2="YES","show",IF(C2="NO","show",IF(C1="NO","hide",D1)))
   ```
3. Then use [AutoFilter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/quick-start-filter-data-by-using-an-autofilter-08647e19-11d1-42f6-b376-27b932e186e0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to filter by `show` in column D

   [image]
   *<sup>Image 1: How to filter the helper column D by 'show'.</sup>*

---

With VBA you would need to loop through all data rows and check if you are in a `NO` subrow or not:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideSubRowsWithNo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  'define your sheet here

    Dim LastRow As Long  'get last used row in column A
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim NoArea As Boolean
    Dim RowsToHide As Range

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow  'loop through all data rows
        If ws.Cells(iRow, "C").Value = "NO" Then  'check if row has NO in column C (note this is case sensitive)
            NoArea = True  'mark that we are in a NO subrow
        ElseIf ws.Cells(iRow, "C").Value = "YES" Then
            NoArea = False  'mark that we are NOT in a NO subrow
        ElseIf ws.Cells(iRow, "C").Value = vbNullString Then  'if column c is empty
            If NoArea Then 'check if we are in a NO subrow
                If RowsToHide Is Nothing Then
                    Set RowsToHide = ws.Rows(iRow)
                Else
                    Set RowsToHide = Union(RowsToHide, ws.Rows(iRow))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

    If Not RowsToHide Is Nothing Then
        RowsToHide.Select 'just to show which rows would be hidden for production use the line below to hide the rows
        'RowsToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer @Pᴇʜ, but I need a macro solution

Comment: Then loop through all rows with data (you will find tutorials for that, as this is a very common task) and check if column C of the current row is `"no"` if so hide all subsequent rows until column C is `"yes"` or the end of data is reached. Give it a try and if you get stuck or error ask a question about it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I am studying loops now and I think that's exactly what I need. I still don't understand how to set up borders (until Yes).

Comment: thank you very much!!!! With your code I can highlight all the rows, which I need to hide, but when I want to hide them (RowsToHide.Hidden = True) I get an error (400).

Comment: @Romubay Sorry of course it needs to be the entire row hidden: `RowsToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: all right. Is it possible to extend the last piece of code, so that it will hide rows then NO, and bring them back if YES? I have put an example of code to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub HideNo()    
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim hide As Integer
    Dim lstrow As Integer

    lstrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    hide = 1

    For y = 2 To lstrow
        If Range("C" & y).Value = "NO" Then
            hide = 0          
        ElseIf Range("C" & y).Value = "YES" Then
            hide = 1         
        End If

        If hide = 1 Then
            Rows(y).EntireRow.Hidden = False               
        ElseIf hide = 0 Then
            Rows(y).EntireRow.Hidden = True       
        End If 
    Next y
End Sub
```

This should do what you were asking for You'd need to run the macro after you had your data filled in.

Comment: Row counting variables need to be `Long` because Excel has more rows than fit into `Integer`, so declare all of them as `Long`. • Note that the OP wants the row with `No` in it visible but only the subgroups `2.1. - 2.3` should be hidden, the group `2.` with the `No` should still be visible.